# Jquery : Remove created element if CLICKED button value is xxx

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a div (with contents in it) onclick on  `"Information button"` and the value `"Information button"` changes to "Go Back" using `$("#").toggle();`

now the div i created earlier is not being removed although I have this

`if ($(this).val() == 'Go Back') {$('#msg').remove();}`

Here is my code;

```
$("#InformationButton").one('click',function () {



                        $('<div>stackoverflow -- dynamically created content</div> ', {
                        id: 'Interface',
                        text: ''}).appendTo('#main-section');
                        $("#Interface").toggle("slow", "linear");


                    })

                    $('.InformationButton').click(function () {

                        $(".PageBody").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");

                        $(this).val($(this).val() == 'Information button' ? 'Go Back' : 'Information button');
                        $("#Interface").toggle();

                    });

                    $('.InformationButton').click(function () {

                        if ($(this).val() == 'Go Back') {
                            $('#Interface').remove();
                        }

                    });
```

I need to remove the `#Interface` if user click on the information button and id value =="Go Back" and show .PageBody.

Comment: Whether `$('<div>stackoverflow -- dynamically created content</div> ', {id: 'Interface', text: ''}).appendTo('#main-section');` it is creating div with id `Interface`?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out -- it doesn't add id: 'Interface', checking that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `$('.ImpToExcel').click(function () {` this refers to the clicked element with class `.ImpToExcel`.

You need to save the reference to `this`

```
$("#InformationButton").one('click',function () {
   $self = $(this);


   //rest of the code

   $('.ImpToExcel').click(function () {

     //rest of the code
     $self.val($self.val() == 'Information button' ? 'Go Back' : 'Information button');
     //rest of the code
   });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, by the way ImpToExcel class is attached to the InformationButton, i used ImpToExcel  to change the button's value